# Trying to fetch API I created to react component

Tags: reactjs

So I created test API and added few test records to the DB.

Now when I wanted to fetch the data in react component I'm getting this error

```
Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

when I try to console.log the data to see if it works. I asume it has something to do with the fact, that I run the API server on port 8080 and react app on 3000 (when I switched api to 3000 and clicked "back arrow" I saw a console.log with the data, but when I refreshed the site it realised the API is "occupying" this URL now).

How can I fix that? Here is the important part of the code, if I need to post more please do let me know.

API (app\src\apiTest\index.js):

```
const express = require('express');
const routes = require('./api.js');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();

//connect to mongodb
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/drugDB');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

//serving files (folder name)
app.use(express.static('../../../src'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

//initialize routes
app.use('/api', routes);

//error handling middleware
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    res.send({error: err.message})
})



app.listen(process.env.port || 8080, function(){
    console.log('listening')
})
```

2nd file in API

```
const express = require('express');
const Drug = require('./models/drug');

const router = express.Router();

//get list of drugs
router.get('/leki', function (req, res) {
    Drug.find({}).then(function(drugs){
        res.send(drugs);
    })
})

router.post('/leki', function (req, res, next) {
    Drug.create(req.body).then(function (drug) {
        res.send(drug);
    }).catch(next);

})

router.put('/leki/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    Drug.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, req.body).then(function () {
        Drug.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }).then(function (drug) {
            res.send(drug);
        })
    })
})

router.delete('/leki/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    Drug.findByIdAndRemove({ _id: req.params.id }).then(function (drug) {
        res.send({ type: drug })
    });
})

module.exports = router;
```

react component (app\src\components\MainPanel\panel.js):

```
componentDidMount(){
    fetch('/api/leki').then(function(data){
        console.log(data.json());
    })
}
```

Comment: Could you add code for your leki endpoint as well please, the error is suggesting that you're not receiving JSON back in response

Comment: Edited, is that what you wanted linas?

Comment: Yes thank you, check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

The error is suggesting that you're not receiving JSON back in response. Which is the case because inside of your `leki` endpoint you're using `res.send(drug);` which sends data back as HTML, change it to `res.json({data: drug})` and then inside of componentDidMount:

```
  componentDidMount(){
      fetch('/api/leki', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {       
             'Accept': 'application/json',
         }
      }).then(function(response){
          return response.json();
      }).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data.drug)
      })
  }
```

Comment: Im getting the same old error + "GET http://localhost:3000/api/leki 404 (Not Found)". I replaced res.send(drug) in router.get and then also in the rest of the places, didnt help. Also, i dont think it should look for the data on port 3000 when its set to 8080.

Comment: Your react app is running on port 3000 and your backend on 8080? In your package.json of react app do you have at the bottom:   "proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
?

Comment: Correct. And yes, I double checked, at the end of my package.json i have  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080".

Comment: What does this line do: app.use(express.static('../../../src'));  seems like you're serving your react app from within your api server try commenting that line out

Comment: It was supposedly (according to tutorial I used, im new to creating API) allowing other parts of the app to use it. But apparently it does nothing, because commenting it out changes nothing, still getting the same errors.

Comment: Well you must also have other problems somewhere else which I can't help you solve because I don't have access to your codebase and your environment

Comment: I found a workaround, i forcefuly set the fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/leki'), then used chrome extenstion to allow Access-Control-Allow-Origin and I'm able to access the promise ("response.json()") in this state: http://prntscr.com/gvqjvx  Now I need to figure out how to access this data, because the rest of your and mine code gets just "undefined" when I try to console log it, hopefuly I will be able to figure it out somehow.

Comment: Changed console.log(data.drug) to console.log(data.data) and now I have access to it. Thanks, while not exactly optimal it gets me going in the right direction until I will be able to talk with senior programmer I know :) Thanks

Comment: Well at this point I'm just lost with whatever you're doing lol but whatever works for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('/api/leki')
    .then(function (resolve) { return resolve.json(); })
    .then(function (resolveJson) {
      console.log(resolveJson);
    });
}
```

Look at this for more information:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch

Comment: panel:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Exact same error. I suppose there is an issue with how I try to connect the API with my app, not how I used fetch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow [Cross Origin requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) by setting a header in your response in the backend.
Place this code where you send your response:

```
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
```

Comment: While not exactly solving my issue I was able to figure out how to force my app to use the port 8080. Won't work outside of my PC, but ill get it soirted out in the future hopefully